# Homepage and news page loads, no other do

Tags: react-router

Other then Homepage and News element no other page loads. Please Solve my problem

```
 <Layout>
              <div className="routes">
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
                  <Route path="/" element={<Cryptocurrencies />} />
                  <Route path="/" element={<Exchanges />} />
                  <Route path="/" element={<CryptoDetails />} />
                  <Route path="/*" element={<News />} />
                </Routes>
              </div>
            </Layout>
```

Comment: Each route path should be unique. The last 3 `"/"` won't render unless they are given a unique path.

Answer (score 0):

I believe each route needs a different path.

Example, if the address you want to point to the exchanges page is 'your-domain.com/exchanges' that route should be:

```
<Route path="exchanges" element={<Exchanges />} />
```

Also see the [react Router API reference examples here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route).

The '*' in your '/*' path for news is a wildcard and will match everything and anything that could be in the path.